# USB keyboard does not load after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: kernel, 13.10

**Problem:**
Running kernel 3.11.0-12-generic after a Ubuntu upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 my USB keyboard is not recognised, thus I am not able to unlock my encrypted disk. I suspect it might be related to a minimal/incorrect install of initrd.

**Question:**
How do I go about getting the newest kernel to recognise my generic USB keyboard, allowing me to unlock my encrypted disk?

**What I have tried:**
I have already re-installed the newest kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image
```

and I have also updated the initrd:

```
update-initramfs -c -k 3.11.0-12-generic
```

**Back story:**
I just completed upgrading my Ubuntu system from 13.04 to 13.10. When I subsequently rebooted by system I was no longer able to enter my encryption password (passphrase) as the keyboard drivers did not load.

**Temporary workaround:**
Earlier in the boot process (before the keyboard stops working) I was able to enter GRUB menu were I choose to boot from an older kernel (3.8.0-31-generic) which did load the USB keyboard drivers. This is currently the kernel I am running.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1238194

Add `ohci_pci` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and save

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot and Enjoy! :-)